# What methods could be used for determining the concentration of Zn2+ in a solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know that complexometric titration with EDTA is one method. What other methods could be used?

Comment: Have you searched Google Scholar? Use these key words atomic absorption spectrophotometer, ICP for zinc.

Answer (score 1):

- Mass spectroscopy(MS)
- HPLC-MS, if separation is required
- Atomic emission spectroscopy(AES)
  (Probably)
- Polarography/voltammetry

The list is not exhaustive.